# Cloning form array in twig, symfony 2

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig, formbuilder

How do you copy a form array built using form builder in symfony 2 at the twig level?

I have the form group below, which creates a multi-layered form

```
 {{ form_row(form.products.ItemOptions) }}
```

I was hoping to copy this array    form.products.Options into new array in twig so i can display and edit it in another section on the same page.

I have tried using twigs merge function, and also jquery. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "I have tried using twigs merge function"... can you show us that? Generally speaking, need to merge arrays in your twig usually (not always) points to a bad implementation decision somewhere along the road...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) for that.

```
{% set productOptions = form.products.Options %}
```

Note that you can also customize the view of your forms via [AbstractType::buildView()](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Form/AbstractType.html#method_buildView)

Comment: That was what i was looking for, but it once it creates the form the original form array is empty. Maybe its not possible to reuse two of the same forms in this way.

Comment: Can you add some detail about exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish by "reusing" parts of a form view?

Comment: Yeah i'm looking to display some of the form rows in another section of the form, without messing with the form builder on the php if possible. The only reason i'm trying to keep a copy of both forms is so the original forms value is recorded correctly (there's alot of ajax, jquery form logic on the page). If i can strip the rows out, and keep the values and attributes the same then that is the perfect option though. The full code with attributes is {{ form_row(form.product.itemOptions, { 'style': 'horizontal', 'label_col': 0, 'widget_col': 12 } ) }}

Answer (score 0):

the form that is rendered uses an Entity. (e.g. Product). Since you already have an instance of that entity in your controller you could simply add this entity to your Twig data. 
        return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'products' => $products,
        ));
    }

In twig you can simply do something like:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% for itemOption in product.itemOptions %}
        {{ itemOption }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or you make a second formType class and generate a second form in your controller using the new formType and add your form to you Twig data.

Comment: Is it possible to make a second formType class when the original is generated from an entity. Won't all the naming conventions need to be the same, so the form will just have the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my issue with simple jquery if it helps anyone. By using `appendTO()` command i was able to strip out rows on the dom and reorganise them. Also using `$( "#divID" ).clone().appendTo( "#NewPosition" );` allowed me to display the form in two locations, although as the properties are also copied it wasn't the most functional method.